# filepicker.io not displaying fliepicker on deployed Meteor site

Tags: deployment, meteor, filepicker.io

I have Filepicker.io set up and working perfectly on the localhost of the Meteor site I am developing. However, when I do a deploy:

```
meteor deploy -P domain.com
```

it bundles everything, uploads it, but...there's no button or drop area. Instead, just this:

```
<input type="filepicker-dragdrop" id="attachment">
```

I'm confused, because I'm not sure if I need to do anything else to have it recognize the particular domain, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the filepicker js isn't being run.

Looks like this question should help: [trouble with filepicker script loading in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220539/trouble-with-filepicker-script-loading-in-meteor)